# Selecionar todo o texto textbox

Tags: vb.net

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
Private Sub nct_focus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles nCT.GotFocus, nCT.Click
    sender.SelectAll()
End Sub
```

o que acontece é o seguinte, ele funciona bem, porém tenho uns 40 textboxes no meu form, já dei uma olhada e gostaria de chamar essa função em todos os textboxes do meu form...

alguma forma de fazer isso sem ter que repetir o código toda a vez que incluir um novo textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta adicionar os elementos que terão os eventos tratados (*handled*) pelo método separando por vírgulas:

```
Private Sub nct_focus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles text1.GotFocus, text2.GotFocus, text2.GotFocus.... etc....
    sender.SelectAll()
End Sub
```

Agora se quiser que automaticamente todos os *TextBoxes* do seu form tenham o evento associados ao seu método, você pode pesquisar todos os elementos dentro do seu form, na collection `Controls`, verificar se não do tipo `TextBox` e associar o evento.

Pode fazer isso ao carregar o form, algo assim:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
   ' Para cada controle, verificar o tipo e associar ao evento
    For Each ctrl As Control In Me.Controls

        If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Then
            Dim textBox As TextBox = CType(ctrl, TextBox)
            AddHandler textBox.GotFocus, AddressOf nct_focus
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: do primeiro modo eu já sabia que dava pra fazer, queria algo aproximado com a segunda forma, porem já havia testado dessa forma que você passou, infelizmente não funcionou

Comment: o que não funcionou? ele não associou os eventos, ou associou e não fez o que esperava?

Comment: não associou os eventos, acho que a saída vai ser fazer como na primeira forma

Comment: entendi.... só para confirmar, se converter o sender não funciona? nessa linha `sender.SelectAll()` sender é um Object, não precisa converter para `TextBox`?

Comment: Consegui fazer funcionar, era um erro de análise meu, havia um tabcontrol dentro do meu form, o que fazia com que o evento não fosse adicionado, pois não existia nenhum textbox diretamente no form, mas sim no tabcontrol.

Comment: Legal, isso me faz lembrar muitas coisas, faz tempo q não trabalho com forms.. boa sorte :)